# How to retrieve data from firebase and show particular data?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am setting a function that allows the user to retrieve data that they have store inside the database. When user types in the value of data, it checks and displays the data to user when the is information already stored in the database. How can I retrieve the data by search 'icNumber' and display all the data that under that child value?

Here’s a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJLFk.png) of what I am trying to achieve.

Lastly, here’s my code

```
func displayRecord() {
        //guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        Database.database().reference().child("Patient_Data").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let name = snapshot.value as? String else { return }
            guard let icNumber = snapshot.value as? String else { return }
            guard let gender = snapshot.value as? String else { return }
            guard let phoneNumber = snapshot.value as? String else { return }
            guard let medicationAllergic = snapshot.value as? String else { return }
            guard let smokerRecord = snapshot.value as? String else { return }
            self.welcomeLabel.text = "Name, \(name)"
            self.welcomeLabel.text = "IC Number, \(icNumber)"
            self.welcomeLabel.text = "Gender, \(gender)"
            self.welcomeLabel.text = "Phone Number, \(phoneNumber)"
            self.welcomeLabel.text = "Medication Allergic, \(medicationAllergic)"
            self.welcomeLabel.text = "Smoker Record, \(smokerRecord)"

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                self.welcomeLabel.alpha = 1
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change your `displayRecord` method to take an entry id ("-Lq_y67Rndy3BLyaKA7Q") so you see only one entry at a time, instead of every patients' data in your system. Then, you need to cast your snapshot value to a dictionary that matches the types stored on your database. That is the `guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:String] else { return }` line.

```swift
func displayRecord(entryId: String) {
    Database.database().reference().child("Patient_Data/\(entryId)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:String] else { return }

        let name = dict["name"]
        let icNumber = dict["icNumber"]
        let gender = dict["gender"]
        let phoneNumber = dict["phoneNumber"]
        let medicationAllergic = dict["medicationAllergic"]
        self.welcomeLabel.text = "Name, \(name)"
        self.welcomeLabel.text = "IC Number, \(icNumber)"
        self.welcomeLabel.text = "Gender, \(gender)"
        self.welcomeLabel.text = "Phone Number, \(phoneNumber)"
        self.welcomeLabel.text = "Medication Allergic, \(medicationAllergic)"
        self.welcomeLabel.text = "Smoker Record, \(smokerRecord)"

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.welcomeLabel.alpha = 1
        })
    }
}
```

It seems that you think that your snapshot's value will be of type `String`. This must be why you are casting the value as string, and to multiple properties (it makes no sense to do this, even if your snapshot value was a string).

You may also want to consider whether all of these values should be stored as Strings on your backend.

Comment: yes, all my values is store as String but it still didn't display anything.

Comment: Your values are stored as strings, but you aren’t referencing the individual values, that would require something along the lines of `Database.database().reference().child("Patient_Data/-Lq_y67Rndy3BLyaKA7Q/name").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in }`

Comment: Instead, you are referencing the parent of those nodes, which would be of type `[String:String]`